# Rails database sharding and stored procedures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i'm using the tchandy/octopus gem for database sharding.
And i have a requirement, is to execute stored procedures on different sql server databases. How can i do this using this gem?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the ActiveRecord SQLServer Adapter, checkout:

[http://rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/3.2.9/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Sqlserver/DatabaseStatements:execute_procedure](http://rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/3.2.9/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Sqlserver/DatabaseStatements%3aexecute_procedure)

do something like this in your code

```
class Pro::DataImport < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.update(user)
    self.execute_procedure("Stored Procedure Name", arg1, arg2)
  end
end
```

Every normal SQL query is converted to a stored procedure to be executed.  That is how the SQL Server adapter for ActiveRecord works.  So you only have to worry about this for permanent stored procedures defined in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.

I'm doing something like this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.call_proc_example shard
        Octopus.using( shard.to_sym ) do
            self.select_all( "exec [dbo].[proc_name_example];" );
        end
    end
end
```

It works for me, since i have many databases to execute procedures.